# Why am I getting "Parameter is incorrect" when updating Access database using DataAdapter?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, oledb, oledbdataadapter

**What I'm trying to do:**

Update a .mdb Access database using a DataTable and DataAdapter. Please see my code below.

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
    Jet OLEDB:Database Password=iaggyah;User ID=Admin;
    Data Source=C:\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa\resources\Survey1.mdb;"))
        {
            con.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [SurveyTest1]", con);
            surveyTbl.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            surveyTbl.Rows[0]["SurveyName"] = "test2";
            
            try
            {
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [SurveyTest1]", con);

                OleDbCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);

                cmdBuilder.QuotePrefix = "[";
                cmdBuilder.QuoteSuffix = "]";

                adapter.DeleteCommand = cmdBuilder.GetDeleteCommand();

                adapter.InsertCommand = cmdBuilder.GetInsertCommand();

                adapter.UpdateCommand = cmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();

                adapter.Update(surveyTbl);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string error = e.Message;
            }
        }
```

**Problem**

When it hits 'adapter.Update' line, it  throws an OleDbException with the message "The parameter is incorrect". Please see the error details below:

Error code: -2147024809
Source: System.Data.Common
Stack trace:

```
    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatusErrors(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdatedRowStatus(RowUpdatedEventArgs rowUpdatedEvent, BatchCommandInfo[] batchCommands, Int32 commandCount)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataRow[] dataRows, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.UpdateFromDataTable(DataTable dataTable, DataTableMapping tableMapping)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Update(DataTable dataTable)
at Tests.Test.UpdateTest_ReturnsTrue() in C:\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa\aaa\Test.cs:line 251
```

I've googled the problem extensively and I haven't found anything that has been relevant.
I've tried writing an update command and updating it that way, and that seems to work. Therefore,
the other alternative I thought of was just to update each row in a for loop, but I need to be able to update any table in the database at runtime, so that might make dynamic updates difficult with different data types. I think I'd be forced to just use varchar (unless I'm mistaken??).

Additional details:

Windows 10

.NET framework 4.7.2

Visual Studio 2019

A class library project

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You haven't assigned `surveyTbl` to a type. You're using it but what is it? Are you assigning it before the using stmt?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're doing. [Check this out](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/26/parameter-queries-in-asp-net-with-ms-access).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. I just used a different work around.